# How to create venn diagram in R studio from group of three frequency column

Tags: r, rstudio, data-analysis

How to create a venn diagram in R from

dataFrame:

```
user  has_1  has_2  has_3
3431  true   false  true 
3432  false  true   false 
3433  true   false  false 
3434  true   false  false 
3435  true   false  false 
3436  true   false  false
```

There are thousands such row.

I want to show how many users have **has_1**, **has_2** and **has_3** and their intersections as it is shown in Venn digram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using the package `venneuler`:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "user  has_1  has_2  has_3
3431  true   false  true
3432  false  true   false
3433  true   false  false
3434  true   false  false
3435  true   false  false
3436  true   false  false", colClasses = c("numeric", rep("logical", 3)))
library(venneuler) 
plot(venneuler(df[-1]))
```

[Look at this graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIlNIVXpIns):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to label the counts also?

Comment: You mean just the counts for the three circles? That would be `vd <- venneuler(df[-1]); vd$labels <- paste(vd$labels, colSums(df[-1])); plot(vd)` (or just rename the column names of df beforehand).

Comment: I already have dataFrame variable, I created using `dataFrame<-read.csv etc` how to use that DataFrame in your `read.Table`

Comment: Just replace `df` by `myDataFrameName`? You maybe have to convert factors into logical values by using `myDataFrameName[, -1] <- sapply(myDataFrameName[, -1], as.logical)`.

Comment: Thanks much, strangely after I did `myDataFrameName[, -1] <- sapply(myDataFrameName[, -1], as.logical)` all values in column 2 to 3 became  `NA` from `t` and `f`

Comment: I thought you got `true`s and `false`es. Try `dataFrame[, -1] <- sapply(dataFrame[, -1], function(x) as.logical(toupper(x)))`.

Comment: awesome you are a life safer :)

Comment: `vd$labels <- paste(vd$labels, colSums(df[-1])); ` mislables, the bigger circle has lesser count than the smaller one.