# Overlapping two gene sets ,finding their overlap significance and plotting them

Tags: r, overlap, venn-diagram

> (Fig. 3a, b, Extended Data Fig. 3a, b and Supplementary Table 1).
> After 48 h, more than one-third of the transcriptome was
> differentially expressed (>5,000 genes; 405 genes encoding for
> proteins in the extracellular region, Gene Ontology (GO) accession
> 0005576), significantly overlapping with the gene expression changes
> of A375 tumours in vivo after 5 days of vemurafenib treatment (Fig.
> 3a, b and Extended Data Fig. 3c). Similar extensive gene expression
> changes were observed in Colo800 and UACC62 melanoma cells treated
> with vemurafenib and H3122 lung adenocarcinoma cells treated with
> crizotinib (Extended Data Fig. 3d). Despite different cell lineages,
> different oncogenic drivers, and different targeted therapies we
> observed a significant overlap between the secretome of melanoma and
> lung adenocarcinoma cells (P < 9.11 × 10−5)

The original [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14336/figures/7)

[image: figure]

I would like to see similar to the **figure f** where it shows the intersection and significance overlap. To achieve that i got this code working till the intersection part but I dont know how to run the significance part.

```
library(reshape2)
library(venneuler)
RNA_seq_cds <- read.csv("~/Downloads/RNA_seq_gene_set.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
head(RNA_seq_cds)
ATAC_seq <- read.csv("~/Downloads/ATAC_seq_gene_set.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
head(ATAC_seq)
RNA_seq <- RNA_seq_cds
ATAC_seq <- ATAC_seq

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184/combining-two-data-frames-of-different-lengths
cbindPad <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args, nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx) {
    if (nrow(x) < mx) {
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      if (ncol(x) == 0) {
        return(padTemp)
      } else {
        return(rbind(x, padTemp))
      }
    } else {
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args, pad, mx)
  return(do.call(cbind, rs))
}

dat <- cbindPad(ATAC_seq, RNA_seq)

vennfun <- function(x) { 
  x$id <- seq(1, nrow(x))  #add a column of numbers (required for melt)
  xm <- melt(x, id.vars="id", na.rm=TRUE)  #melt table into two columns (value & variable)
  xc <- dcast(xm, value~variable, fun.aggregate=length)  #remove NA's, list presence/absence of each value for each variable (1 or 0)
  rownames(xc) <- xc$value  #value column=rownames (required for Venneuler)
  xc$value <- NULL  #remove redundent value column
  xc  #output the new dataframe
}

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121956/legend-venn-diagram-in-venneuler
VennDat <- vennfun(dat)
genes.venn <- venneuler(VennDat)
genes.venn$labels <- c("RNA", "\nATAC" )
# plot(genes.venn, cex =15, )
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225151/how-to-create-venn-diagram-in-r-studio-from-group-of-three-frequency-column
#https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13301_6641d73cfac741a59c0a851feb99e98b.html   
vd <- venneuler(VennDat)
vd$labels <- paste(genes.venn$labels, colSums(VennDat))
plot(vd, cex=10)
text(.3, .45, 
     bquote(bold("Common ="~.(as.character(sum(rowSums(VennDat) == 2))))), 
     col="red", cex=1)

LABS <- vd$labels
```

The above code gives me the intersection plot [image: intersection_plot]

Now the **significance** part how do i do that between two gene sets and show it as shown in the original figure.

My [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tISk5kfAJaH5b-VCjeRUVaVCIwwgA_zK?usp=sharing) which i have used to generate the above plot

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about how to place any text under your figure, just use 'text' as you did before. It's just some guessing on which `x=` and `y=` coordinates.  The`xpd=TRUE` allows you to plot over the margin.

```
VennDat <- vennfun(dat)
vd <- venneuler(VennDat)
vd$labels <- paste(c("RNA", "ATAC"), colSums(VennDat))

plot(vd, cex=10, border=c(NA, 'red'), col=c('#6b65af', '#ad7261'))
text(x=.5, y=.5, sum(rowSums(VennDat) == 2), xpd=TRUE)
text(.5, .15, 'overlap\n', xpd=TRUE)
text(.5, .13, bquote(italic(p)*'< 9.11E-55'), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

I also adjusted some parameters of `plot`. You may inspect the code of the plotting method using:

```
venneuler:::plot.VennDiagram
```

If you want to know how significance is calculated, you should post your question at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thank you for the answer actually I didn't know how to calculate the test required to know the overlap significance

Comment: shall I repost the question again on the other site?

Comment: @PesKchan Yes of course. You can also consider [bioinformatics.stackexchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).